# Delete files inside a folder (Visual Studio 2017 VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

I want to delete all possible files inside a specific folder, without any window opening, and if an error occurs because of a file that can not be deleted, it just does not delete it.

Example:

```
DeleteFilesInsideFolder("C:\Windows\Temp")
```

With no return messages or errors.

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that will delete all of the files in the specified folder:

```
Imports System.IO

Sub DeleteFilesInsideFolder(ByVal target_folder_path As String)

     ' loop through each file in the target directory
     For Each file_path As String In Directory.GetFiles(target_folder_path)

          ' delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
          Try
               File.Delete(file_path)
          Catch ex As Exception

          End Try

     Next

End Sub
```

However, if you also want to delete subdirectories, then you'll need to use this modified version:

```
Imports System.IO

    Sub DeleteFilesInsideFolder(ByVal target_folder_path As String, ByVal also_delete_sub_folders As Boolean)

         ' loop through each file in the target directory
         For Each file_path As String In Directory.GetFiles(target_folder_path)

              ' delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
              Try
                   File.Delete(file_path)
              Catch ex As Exception

              End Try

         Next


         ' if sub-folders should be deleted
         If also_delete_sub_folders Then

             ' loop through each file in the target directory
             For Each sub_folder_path As String In Directory.GetDirectories(target_folder_path)

                  ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
                  Try
                       Directory.Delete(sub_folder_path, also_delete_sub_folders)
                  Catch ex As Exception

                  End Try

             Next

         End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim path As String = "E:\NewFolder\"
    DeleteDirectory(path)
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteDirectory(path As String)
    If Directory.Exists(path) Then
        'Delete all files from the Directory
        For Each filepath As String In Directory.GetFiles(path)
            File.Delete(filepath)
        Next
        'Delete all child Directories
        For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(path)
            DeleteDirectory(dir)
        Next
        'Delete a Directory
        Directory.Delete(path)
    End If
End Sub
```